# Spring application starts but I always see the "Whitelabel Error Page"

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application split into two modules. A 'core' module where I have my entities, repositories and services and a 'web' module where I want to create some Rest Controllers to work with that data. I will show you the modules structures and the files I have so far:

The core module:

```
|-- core
    |-- model
        |-- client
            |-- Client.java
    |-- repositories
        |-- client
            |-- IClientRepository.java
    |-- services
        |-- client
            |-- IClientService.java
            |-- ClientServiceImpl.java
```

Client.java:

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="clients")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="PHONE")
    private String phone;

    public Client () {

    }

    public Client (String name, String email, String phone) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "[" + id + "] " + name + " (" + email + ", " + phone + ")";
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

IClientRepository.java:

```
package repositories.client;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import model.Client;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface IClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Integer> {

    List<Client> findAll ();

    Optional<Client> findById (Integer id);

    Client save(Client client);

    void deleteById (Integer ID);

}
```

IClientService.java:

```
package services.client;

import model.Client;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface IClientService {

    List<Client> findAll ();
    Optional<Client> findById (Integer id);
    void deleteById (Integer id);
    Client save (Client client);
}
```

ClientServiceImpl.java:

```
package services.client;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import model.Client;
import repositories.client.IClientRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements IClientService{

    @Autowired
    private IClientRepository repository;

    @Override
    public List<Client> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Client> findById(Integer id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Client save(Client client) {
        return repository.save(client);
    }
}
```

The web module:

```
|-- web
    |-- rest
        |-- client
            |-- ClientController.java
    |-- main
        |-- Application.java
```

ClientController.java:

```
package rest.client;

import model.Client;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import services.client.IClientService;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private IClientService clientService;

    @RequestMapping("/clients")
    public List<Client> getAllClients() {
        return clientService.findAll();
    }

}
```

Application.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"rest"})
@ComponentScan({"services"})
@EntityScan("model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("repositories")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I use the MySql database that comes with xampp and I know that the core module works because I used it in another project with a simple console interface. Also, IntelliJ creates in every module a 'resources' folder where I have an application.properties file containing the following:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movierental
spring.datasource.username=root
```

Now, the core module works on its own, the rest controller also works if I simply return a statically created list with clients, but when I use them together in order to get data from the database to the rest controller it doesn't work. I go to 'localhost:8080/clients' and I get the Whitelabel error page and I have no idea why. Is there something I do wrong here?

EDIT:

After I access the link, this is what I get in the console:

```
2018-05-31 20:09:48.128  INFO 13804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-05-31 20:09:48.128  INFO 13804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-05-31 20:09:48.147  INFO 13804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
```

And this is what appears on the Whitelabel page:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu May 31 20:09:48 EEST 2018
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>
> No message available

Comment: What appears in the console or on the whitelabel page? Should have an exception

Comment: I edited the question and added the console output and the whitelabel page content.

Comment: Your component scan is not picking up the RestController. You would normally have everything in the same root package.

Comment: It doesn't work even if I have the Application class in the same package as the RestController. Just tried that right now.

Comment: When you properly wire a request, the log should read:  s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL to MethodName. If it doesn't, your restcontroller is not initialized.

Comment: Ok. It's not mapping the Controller, but the Application class and the RestController class are in the same package now...

Answer (score 0):

The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` with their default attributes.

Here is the sample code on how to override the default behavour.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example")
```

Or you can specify multiple packages as shown below:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example", "com.example2"})
```

**Spring Boot default app structure and component scan**

Turns out, by convention if your main app class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and is in a package with all your code in packages below this point, then those subpackages are scanned by default.

```
    package example.simplespringboot;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

All packages below example.simplespringboot in the example by default will be scanned for Spring components

[image]

[See the docks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

Comment: And that's why I use the '@ComponentScan', '@EntityScan' and '@EnableJpaRepository'... to tell the application where are my classes. If I don't use these annotations the application doesn't even start and it tells me that it doesn't know where is the ClientService

Comment: try to remove only main package in  your structure.

Comment: I can't get it to work... And apparently, the RestController is not initialized... the "/clients" url is not mapping to the method in the Controller.. And I placed the Application in the same package as the Controller...\

Comment: try to add a endpoint test in you Application class and see if is mapping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172180/discussion-between-allan-braga-and-xyntell).